# Flex - HTTPService and gzipped responses?

Tags: apache-flex, gzip

I have a Flex client making RESTful calls to a webservice using HTTPService.  The server is returning JSON responses, which we would like to compress. Can Flex using HTTPService handle gzip-encoded responses?  If so, what steps are required to make it work (e.g., which headers to set, how to decompress, etc.)?  If not, can you suggest a simple alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Networking calls in Flex apps go through the browser stack.  So it's actually the browser handling the gzip.  So as long as the browser supports it (sends the correct accept-type) then it should just work in a Flex app since the response will already be ungzipped before it gets back to the app.